# OR filter in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am a Neo4j newbie.

I have a Neo4j graph with 3 entities: Person, FirstName, Postcode - they are related to each other as follows:

```
Person -> [:HasFirstName] -> FirstName 

Person -> [:HasPostcode] -> Postcode
```

I have a person in the database: 
Tom with Postcode: LA2 0RN

I have this query:

```
"MATCH(p:Person), (pc:Postcode), (f:FirstName)
WHERE (p)-[:HAS_POSTCODE] -> (pc{value:'LA2 0RN'}) OR (p)-[:HAS_FIRST_NAME]->(f:FirstName {value: "Jerry"})
return DISTINCT p, pc"
```

It does not return any records even if there is a match for Tom based on his postcode. How do I execute an OR statement so that I can return Tom based on his postcode.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, you are trying to filter patterns with patterns.
Using the [WHERE Clause](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#boolean-operations) with variables would be the best approach.
Match the pattern first and then filter on the desired property.

You could use the following Query to match users based on their postcode:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:HasPostcode]->(pc:Postcode)
WHERE pc.value='LA2 0RN'
RETURN p, pc
```

If you want to use an OR condition and find matches for Postcode or Name:

```
MATCH (f)<-[:HAS_FIRST_NAME]-(p:Person)-[:HasPostcode]->(pc)
WHERE pc.value='LA2 0RN' OR f.value='Jerry' OR f.value='Tom'
RETURN f, p, pc
```